# How to send a react-native app to background instead of closing and show it in "Tray"? [iOS and Android]

Tags: android, ios, react-native

First of all, i'm sorry for, perhaps, confusing title - i'll rename it once i'll find answer to question #1 :)

1. What is the name of [this location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vm0Pk.png)? I'll call it "tray" for now
2. What about equivalent of "tray" on ios? How do i name it?
3. I want to put my app in "tray" and show current state of some process. E.g. in the example above aimp player shows current track and allows user to pause playback or change track.
4. I want this app to go to background (and in tray) instead of being closed whatever user does. How do i do that?
5. I assume, the app will be able to continue interaction with the device's bluetooth and wifi while in background/tray. Right?

Comment: Your question appears to be more applicable to android. iOS does not have a "tray". Apps can be suspended on iOS. There are limited background modes in iOS including bluetooth and limited networkinf (e.g audio streaming and periodic data fetch)

Comment: @Paulw11 thank you. How do audio players work in ios? Basically, i want the same - permanent active process. What i need is to use bluetooth and sometimes send POST requests to server.

Comment: There is a specific audio background mode for iOS.  It is described in the iOS application programming guide for Apple. I am sure there will be complexities resulting from using react-native though.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW26